# Using a crud api

Tags: jquery-ui, crud

file:///C:/Users/Adil%20Ali/Downloads/front%20end%20api/intro.html

Above I have a website with some movie-list can anyone list me some suggestions on how to make a crud ui like this: [image]

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>My Movies</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="execute.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
     <ul id = "movielist"></ul>
     <button id = "showMovies">All Movies</button>
 </center>

 <p>idmovielist: <input type="text" id="idmovielist"></p>
 <p>name: <input type="text" id="name"></p>
 <p>thumnail_path: <input type="text" id="thumnail_path"></p>
 <p>description: <input type="text" id="description"></p>
 <p>year_released: <input type="text" id="year_released"></p>
 <p>language_released: <input type="text" id="language_released"></p>
 <button id = "movieAdded">Add Movie</button>
 <button id = "deleteMovie">Delete Movie</button>
 <button id = "updatedMovie">Update Movie</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is my Html
and below is my CSS

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(10, 200, 196);
  font-family: sans-serif
}
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #5a5a5a;
  }

  ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style:none;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-basis: 80%;
  }
```

and lastly below is my jquery

```
$(function(){
  const $movielist = $('#movielist');
  const $idmovielist = $('#idmovielist');
  const $name = $('#name');
  const $thumnail_path = $('#thumnail_path');
  const $description = $('description');
  const $language_released = $('language_released');
  const $year_released = $('year_released');
 $("#showMovies").click(function(){
$.ajax({
  method:"GET",
  url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (response) {
       $.each(response, function(i, movie) {
         $movielist.append('<li>idmovielist: ' + movie.idmovielist + ',name:' + movie.name + ', thumnail_path: ' +
       movie.thumnail_path + ', description: ' + movie.description + ', year_released: ' + movie.year_released +
       ', language_released: ' + movie.language_released + '</li>');
       });
      }
  });
  });
  $("#movieAdded").click(function() {
    const movies = {
      idmovielist: $idmovielist.val(),
      name: $name.val(),
      thumnail_path: $thumnail_path.val(),
      description: $description.val(),
      year_released: $year_released.val(),
      language_released: $language_released.val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
      method:"POST",
      url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/addMovie",
      data: movies,
      success: function (newMovie) {
             $movielist.append('<li>idmovielist: ' + newMovie.idmovielist + ', name:' + newMovie.name + ', thumnail_path: ' +
           newMovie.thumnail_path + ', description: ' + newMovie.description + ', year_released: ' + newMovie.year_released +
           ', language_released: ' + newMovie.language_released + '</li>');
          }
      });
  });
  $("#deleteMovie").click(function() {
    const movies = {
      idmovielist: $idmovielist.val(),
      name: $name.val(),
      thumnail_path: $thumnail_path.val(),
      description: $description.val(),
      year_released: $year_released.val(),
      language_released: $language_released.val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
      method:"DELETE",
      url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/1",
      data: movies,
      success: function (newMovie) {
             $movielist.append('<li>idmovielist: ' + newMovie.idmovielist + ', name:' + newMovie.name + ', thumnail_path: ' +
           newMovie.thumnail_path + ', description: ' + newMovie.description + ', year_released: ' + newMovie.year_released +
           ', language_released: ' + newMovie.language_released + '</li>');
          }
      });
  });
  $("#updatedMovie").click(function() {
    const movies = {
      idmovielist: $idmovielist.val(),
      name: $name.val(),
      thumnail_path: $thumnail_path.val(),
      description: $description.val(),
      year_released: $year_released.val(),
      language_released: $language_released.val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
      method:"PUT",
      url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/update/2",
      data: movies,
      success: function (newMovie) {
             $movielist.append('<li>idmovielist: ' + newMovie.idmovielist + ', name:' + newMovie.name + ', thumnail_path: ' +
           newMovie.thumnail_path + ', description: ' + newMovie.description + ', year_released: ' + newMovie.year_released +
           ', language_released: ' + newMovie.language_released + '</li>');
          }
      });
  });

});
```

So what can I add to make this a crud UI application with the code I have all the request are working my goal is to make this webiste of the UI more interactive

Comment: Please copy your html content

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Also `file:///` will refer to a file on your computer that we cannot reach or view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to make the Crud ui like that you can use the normal table or (bootstrap table) and if your result is of huge number you can use the DataTables https://cdn.datatables.net/ to link you table so that you can have nice navigation and search panel

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
                            <thead style="background-color:#ddd;" class="table-borderless">
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">1</td>
                                    <td>Home</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Edit
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Delete
      </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        
                        
                        <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: what if I want to add multiple columns and rows I wanted to add all the movie names

Comment: you could automate it using the JavaScript when click the add button the modal will open then you will append the data in the table..